# C# bool value as string is always null

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable, tostring

I'm attempting to dump variable property information to a simple string but when it gets to my nullable bools, the `as string` always returns null --even if the actual value is true | false!

```
StringBuilder propertyDump = new StringBuilder();

foreach(PropertyInfo property in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
{
    propertyDump.Append(property.Name)
                .Append(":")
                .Append(property.GetValue(myClassInstance, null) as string);
}

return propertyDump.ToString();
```

No exceptions are thrown; quick and the output is exactly what I want except any properties that are `bool?` are always false.  If I quick watch and do `.ToString()` it works!  But I can't guarantee other properties are not, in fact, null.

Can anyone explain why this is? and even better, a workaround?

Comment: That's exactly what `as` is supposed to do.

Comment: I strongly recommend appending "null" if the value is null. You could have a string property that will have the value "" - was it null or was it empty? You can't tell. So you better go with `?:` or `??` so that null values will be written as "null" or some other null-identifying string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `as` operator returns a casted value if the instance is of that exact type, or `null` otherwise.

Instead, you just should `.Append(property.GetValue(...))`; `Append()` will automatically handle nulls and conversions.

Comment: Append will handle nulls, but it will do so by not appending anything - that may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 5):

A bool is not a string, so the as operator returns null when you pass it a boxed boolean.

In your case, you could use something like:

```
object value = property.GetValue(myClassInstance, null);

propertyDump.Append(property.Name)
            .Append(":")
            .Append(value == null ? "null" : value.ToString());
```

If you want to have null values just not append any text, you can just use [Append(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5atxc566.aspx#Y0) directly:

```
propertyDump.Append(property.Name)
            .Append(":")
            .Append(property.GetValue(myClassInstance, null));
```

This will work, but leave null properties in your "propertyDump" output as missing entries.

Answer (score 2):

The nicest solution would be, in my opinion:

```
.Append(property.GetValue(myClassInstance, null) ?? "null");
```

If the value is null, it will append "null", and if not - it will call the value's ToString and append that.

Combining that with Linq instead of a foreach loop, you can have a nice little something:

```
var propertyDump =
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                typeof(myClass).GetProperties().Select(
                    pi => string.Format("{0}: {1}",
                                        pi.Name,
                                        pi.GetValue(myClassInstance, null) ?? "null")));
```

(Looks nicer in the wide screen of VS).

If you compare speeds, by the way, it turns out the string.Join is faster than Appending to a StringBuilder, so I thought you might want to see this solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the type of the property is not string. Change it to:

```
Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(myClassInstance, null))
```

If it's null, it will retrieve null and that's ok. For non-null values it will return the *string representation* of the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a bool to a string.  You must use `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [null coalesing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to handle the Null situations:

```
void Main()
{

   TestIt tbTrue = new TestIt() { BValue = true }; // Comment out assignment to see null

   var result =
    tbTrue.GetType()
          .GetProperties()
          .FirstOrDefault( prp => prp.Name == "BValue" )
          .GetValue( tb, null ) ?? false.ToString();

      Console.WriteLine ( result ); // True

}

public class TestIt
{
   public bool? BValue { get; set; }
}
```